# Moodle isnt sending E-Mails

Tags: email, moodle

I tried setting up a moodle site. So far it works well but it doesnt send e-mails to new Users or other mails at all.

I debugged it but there was no error. I tried it via smpt and the debugger returned `SMTP connect() failed`. Leaving smtp empty didnt work either.

Any clues?

Moodle 2.9.2 (Build: 20150914)